# Tensorflow - Deep MNIST Tutorial - Export classifier to C++

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, classification

I got the trained "Deep MNIST Tutorial" NN, and I know how to test the model with the TensorFlow Python API. Now i want to export the classifier to C++, so i can use it without TensorFlow API.

I know the trained models topology, weights and activation functions. There is any example of this implementation? I searched it, but found how to create and train a NN in C++ and not classifier examples.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following code in Tensorflow tutorial can help?

[TensorFlow C++ Image Recognition Demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image)

This tutorial code is written in C++ and can run without a Tensorflow installed.

But one limitation is that it uses a model which is exported as a "frozen protobuf" `.pb` file.You can download an inception V3 pre-trained model as the page described, or freeze your own model to make one.

If you already saved the model/variables into a checkpoint, the following code would be helpful for freezing your graph:

[freeze_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py)

Or you can add the following code after your training is over to get a frozen  model file as `my_model.pb`:

```
  #...some sess.run loop for training

  output_graph_def = sess.graph_def
  output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
        sess, sess.graph_def, ['some_tensor_names_for_output'])
  output_graph_def = remove_training_nodes(output_graph_def)
  with open('my_model.pb', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped, i didn't know about "frozen protobuf" `.pb`. Your code does not work for me, but i found this blog: https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc#.a8drpmoly